# Microsoft SQL Server 2012 database connectivity with Java (version 8 or 1.8) With example?

Tags: sql-server

```
  -please give some democode

        import java.sql.Connection;
        import java.sql.DriverManager;
        import java.sql.ResultSet;
        import java.sql.SQLException;
        import java.sql.Statement;
        public class JDBCConnectivity
        {
            public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException 
            {       String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433//MSSQLSERVER;databaseName=jdbcexample";
                    String user="",password="";
                    try
                    {
                        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password); 
                        Statement s1 = con.createStatement();
                        ResultSet rs = s1.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM sample");
                        if(rs!=null)
                        {
                            while (rs.next())
                            {
                                 System.out.println(rs.getString(1));

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch(SQLException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
        }
```

Hi techie Im using netbeans IDE, im unable to connect to SQL Server2012. 
default TCP port number is 1433 but still it shows invalid port number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote an invalid port, because, in your string, port will be: 1433//MSSQLSERVER

Your string will be more like:
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;instanceName=MSSQLSERVER;integratedSecurity=true;databaseName=jdbcexample;

Personalize with user and password if not useing integrated.

Source:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428%28v=sql.110%29.aspx